# What is the benefit of creating an abstract class with only final methods?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, final

I mean, obviously, there is no benefit on the polymorphic side,

and declaring (all of) these methods as final would prevent me from overriding them.
And I know IT IS possible to do, and the compiler doesn't prevent you from doing it.

I would love to get a usage example...

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* one.

Comment: What makes you think there is a benefit? Just the fact that the compiler lets you do it? The compiler lets you do _lots_ of un-useful things. `public static void main(String[] args) { throw new RuntimeException("useless"); }`

Comment: Could be that you just really want a base class that can't be instantiated directly but doesn't need any abstract methods. Unusual but shrugs.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

There are some marginal cases where such design, if perhaps not optimal, could at least be motivated. For example, you may have a system of classes, all subclasses of a common parent, where each subclass implements a further interface. There may be a set of interfaces with different formalities, but the same essential function.

In that particalar case it wouldn't hurt to make all the methods `final` and let each subclass add its own methods which make use of them.

Comment: Make methods "final" in "common parent" ?

Comment: Yes. No reason not to. Except that this whole thing would probably be better off with a compositional pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's part of the "core" component. You build something and you design the architecture, and you know that that method should never be changed.

Comment: What you said is true for any final method - is there any advantage in making the class abstract as well as its method final?

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class could have `package` access to some internal methods.

In this case we have

- an incomplete class
- functionality has to stay the same and grants secured access to the internal model

That is all we need to declare a type abstract and all its methods `final`. Consider as an example a `Panel` class that holds the graphics, but not always offers a method to actually make it draw itself - subclasses can have different drawing behaviourse. On the other hand it can offer a `final protected DrawBuffer makeCircle()` or something like that which, for some reason, has to access the internal model to make a `DrawBuffer`.

Comment: As in my example, object composition (an internal helper object implementing those `final` methods) would be more natural if the superclass offers no public API at all.

Answer (score 0):

The JIT can take benefit when some methods declared in such way, when it cannot be overridden. (static, private, final, in final class)

let's imagine you have classes:

```
abstract class A {
     public void doSomething() {
         // default and only realization;
     }
}

class B extends A { ... }
```

Then you write something like:

```
A a = MyAFactory.createA();
a.doSomething();
```

When method cannot be known to be *final*, and there is possible (even if not loaded just now) overridings, compiler makes second line to invoke virtual method. I.e. first it will determine which exactly class A, then looking in virtual method table, and only then call to particular methods.

But! If method is known as it cannot be overridden, then compiler can place to this point direct call to A.doSomething().

So, it is recommended to make method final unless you need them to be overridden.

Let's imagine class like this:

```
abstract class C {

    public abstract int getMin();

    public abstract int getMax();

    public final int getSize() {
        return getMax() - getMin();
    }

}
```

in this example, it is obvious behavior of getSize() and hardly to imagine when it needs to be changed. So, declaring it final, not only gives a benefit by discarding virtual invocation mechanism, but also protects from unintended override of method with particular and predefined behavior.